# Email -- what is the correct way to do new line in email message?

Tags: php, email

```
$message = 'New user registration\n\n
There is a new submission on the site and below are the details.\n\n';
```

I tried to use html but it shows text in email so I change it to plain text. Still cannot make line break.

I am not sure why it is not working as I think.

**EDIT #2**

```
$umessage .=    '<a href="'.$pdflink.'">Download Brochure</a>';
```

The problem is that it displays in email: [Download Brochure](http://localhost/icopen/download.php?f=pummer.pdf)

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use a single quoted string, the line break characters are not interpreted. You need to use `"` to encapsulate your string.

In addition, you should use `\r\n` for compatibility with mail clients.

```
$message = "New user registration\r\n
There is a new submission on the site and below are the details.\r\n";
```

Comment: is there any way around the a href link?

Comment: Please create a new question. You should ask one question per post.

Comment: "When you use a single quoted string, the line break characters are not interpreted." that's what matters. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try using "\r\n" as line breaks.

```
$message = 'New user registration\r\n
There is a new submission on the site and below are the details.\r\n';
```

Comment: That's correct. Please also note burhan's answer, he raised a great point about using double quotation marks with strings containing line breaks.